# How to add up two cells in Excel without a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet in Excel with a list of numbers.  Sometimes I want to move X units from one cell to another.

Let's say I have a classroom of kids, each one has a certain number of marbles. There are 2 columns in the sheet, first column is names, second column is marbles. John gives 375 marbles to Bill. I want to update the sheet.

Currently I pull out a calculator, do the subtraction and addition, and update the cells manually.

This is cumbersome and error-prone.  Is there a better way?

(I know I can write "=8300+375" in the cell but eventually each cell will have a stupidly long formula..)

Comment: I only know how to do it with a formula. I am not sure what you mean by 'without a formula' as everything in Excel is done with formulas. Maybe you should post a screenshot  with a description of just what you are trying to do because I, as well as I am sure others, are confused at this point.

Comment: If you truly want to *replace* the value in `D4` then you have to do this manually, or create a macro.  There's no other way (even with a crazy formula, as formulas can't replace text).  But perhaps you can explain a little more what you're trying to do? Can you not put the difference in another cell, or do you have to replace `D3`?

Comment: Let's say I have a classroom of kids, each one has a certain number of marbles.  There are 2 columns in the sheet, first column is names, second column is marbles. John gives 375 marbles to Bill.  I want to update the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use paste special to easily perform the calculations.

- Enter `-375` in one cell and `375` next to it.
- select your new numbers and press CTRL+C
- Select the cells you want to change.
- in the ribbon / home / paste / "paste special"
- check "add" then "ok"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Máté Juhász*** post inspired me to suggest you VBA Macro, Since it's faster and time saver too. And I do believe that You can handle it.

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that you have data in Range 
  `A2:B4`.
- Put Values you want to Subtract in `C2:C4`.
- From **Developer TAB**, click **Design Mode**
  then **Insert** & From **ActiveX Controls**
  click **Command Button Icon** and draw it on
  the Sheet.
- Click the **Command Button**, you reach to VB 
  editor Windows.
- **Copy & Paste** this code between

  **Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()**

  **End Sub**.

  ```
  Range("C2:C4").Select
   Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial 
    Paste:=xlPasteAll, 
    Operation:=xlSubtract, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C2:C4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ```
- From VB editor Windows click **File menu** then 
  hit **Close & Return to Microsoft Excel**.
- Finally Click on **Command Button**.

*You find New Values in `Column B`,(check Screen shot).*

**N.B.**

*If you want to Subtract Old vlaue from New Value in a Cell only, then you may use this VBA code.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 1 Then

  NewVal = Range("B1").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     Application.Undo

   OldVal = Range("B1").Value
    Range("B1").Value = NewVal
     Range("B1").Value = NewVal - OldVal
      Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
End Sub
```

- Press **ALT+F11** to open VB editor and *Copy & 
  Paste* the above shown code as **Standard 
  Module**.
- As soon you overwrite Value in `B1`, code will
  Subtract it from Old Value and re-write `B1`
  with New Value.

*Adjust Data Range as your need.*